Stripe 'rak_accounts_kyc_basic_read' permission error
I created a key using the WHMCS App from the Stripe Marketplace as per WHMCS and Stripe instructions.  When I try save the new rk_live-*** key this is the error that the Stripe API generates.
invalid_request_error
The provided key 'rk_live_**********************************
***********************************************************3cJbdf' 
does not have the required permissions for this endpoint on account 'acct_********'. 
Having the 'rak_accounts_kyc_basic_read' permission 
would allow this request to continue.

I am using the standard Stripe app on the WHMCS end.
Doing a search for that error on the Stripe site, developer docs, and general internet searches doesn't turn up anything for that specific error.  I checked the permissions of the WHMCS App and they are all set the way Stripe says they should be according to this document.
https://marketplace.stripe.com/apps/whmcs-restricted-auth-keys
Stripe first level support couldn't help so now I am waiting for the next level to get back to me.  I also opened a ticket with WHMCS.
This new restricted API key needs to be installed before Oct29, 2024 at which time the old standard API keys will no longer work.

If this restricted API key is generated by the WHMCS Stripe App, you should reach out to WHMCS and ask why this key isn't working for you. My guess is that they didn't include the necessary permission during the API key generation.

I did reach out to WHMCS.  They said they were able to reproduce the problem on their end and are looking into it.
